# How to print trees with Unicode lines linking the nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, nodes

I am trying to print trees in a way that they look better. Currently, I add tabs before nodes to show at what level they are at. i.e.:

```
top
    middle
        bottom
    middle1
```

What I want to do is replace the tabs with unicode lines to show how they are linked. i.e.:

```
top
├── middle
│   └── bottom
└── middle1
```

This is what [CHAIDS](https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID) trees do, which is what I want to achieve.

My code currently:

```
import pickle


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.nextNodes = []
        self.level = 0

    def printNodes(self, startPoint=None):
        if startPoint:
            if self.data == startPoint:
                print(('\t' * self.level) + self.data)
                if self.nextNodes:
                    for i in self.nextNodes:
                        i.level = self.level + 1
                        i.printNodes()
                self.level = 0
            else:
                if self.nextNodes:
                    for i in self.nextNodes:
                        i.printNodes(startPoint)
        else:
            print(('\t' * self.level) + self.data)
            if self.nextNodes:
                for i in self.nextNodes:
                    i.level = self.level + 1
                    i.printNodes()
            self.level = 0

    def findVal(self, value):
        if self.data != value:
            if self.nextNodes:
                for i in self.nextNodes:
                    if i.findVal(value):
                        return True
        else:
            return True

    def deleteRequest(self, data, startPoint=None):
        if startPoint:
            if self.data == startPoint:
                if self.nextNodes:
                    for counter, i in enumerate(self.nextNodes):
                        if i.data == data:
                            self.nextNodes.pop(counter)
                            return True
                    for i in self.nextNodes:
                        return i.deleteRequest(data)
            else:
                if self.nextNodes:
                    for i in self.nextNodes:
                        return i.deleteRequest(data, startPoint)
        else:
            if self.nextNodes:
                for counter, i in enumerate(self.nextNodes):
                    if i.data == data:
                        self.nextNodes.pop(counter)
                        return True
                for i in self.nextNodes:
                    return i.deleteRequest(data)

    def modifyRequest(self, data, newData, startPoint=None, childModification=None):
        if startPoint:
            if startPoint == self.data or childModification:
                if self.data == data:
                    self.data = newData
                else:
                    if self.nextNodes:
                        for i in self.nextNodes:
                            return i.modifyRequest(data, newData, startPoint, childModification)
        else:
            if self.data == data:
                self.data = newData
                return True
            else:
                if self.nextNodes:
                    for i in self.nextNodes:
                        return i.modifyRequest(data, newData)

    def insertRequest(self, data, parent):
        if self.data == parent:
            for i in self.nextNodes:
                if i.data == data:
                    return False
            temp = Node(data)
            self.nextNodes.append(temp)
            return True
        else:
            if self.nextNodes:
                for i in self.nextNodes:
                    return i.insertRequest(data, parent)


class Head:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headNode = None

    def printList(self, startPoint=None):
        print('--TREE--')
        self.headNode.printNodes(startPoint)
        print('\n')

    def findVal(self, value):
        if self.headNode.findVal(value):
            print("'%s' found" % value)
        else:
            print("'%s' not found" % value)

    def insertNode(self, data, parent):
        if self.headNode.insertRequest(data, parent):
            print("Successfully added a node %s" % data)
        else:
            print("Unsuccessfully added a node")

    def deleteNode(self, data, startingPoint=None):
        if self.headNode.deleteRequest(data, startingPoint):
            print("Node %s has been successfully deleted" % data)
        else:
            print("Node %s has not been deleted - it was not found or it was the head node" % data)

    def modifyNode(self, data, newData, startingPoint=None):
        if self.headNode.modifyRequest(data, newData, startingPoint):
            print("Node %s has successfully changed to %s" % (data, newData))
        else:
            print("Node modification unsuccessful")

help = ''''
---TREE---
use treeN to use tree

-p x       prints the tree, 'x' being the optional starting point

-fv x      finds value 'x' in tree

-i x y     inserts a node, with 'x' being the data and 'y' being the parent
           can't have multiple siblings with the same name

-d x y     deletes a node with 'x' being the data type and optional 'y' being the parent(excluding)

-m x y z   modifies a node, with 'x' being the old data, 'y' being the new data
           and 'z' being the optional parent(excluding)

-s x       save to a file, 'x' being the file name, exclude extension

-l x       load a tree from a file, 'x' being the file name, exclude extension

-exit      exits the program

Rules:
    + one command per input
    + use ; as separators, leave no spaces
'''

print(help)

inp = input("Name of head Node: ")
tree = Head()
NH = Node(inp)
tree.headNode = NH

while True:
    try:
        inp = input('Enter command, type ? for help')
        if inp == '?':
            print(help)

        command = inp.split(';')
        commandL = len(command)
        cmdPrompt = command[0]
        if cmdPrompt == '-exit':
            break

        elif cmdPrompt == '-p':
            if commandL != 1 and commandL != 2:
                print("Incorrect amount of arguments")
                continue
            else:
                if commandL == 2:
                    tree.printList(command[1])
                else:
                    tree.printList()

        elif cmdPrompt == '-fv':
            if commandL != 2:
                print("Incorrect amount of arguments")
                continue
            else:
                tree.findVal(command[1])

        elif cmdPrompt == '-i':
            if commandL != 3:
                print("Incorrect amount of arguments")
                continue
            else:
                tree.insertNode(command[1], command[2])

        elif cmdPrompt == '-d':
            if commandL != 2 and commandL != 3:
                print("Incorrect amount of arguments")
                print(command)
                continue
            else:
                if commandL == 2:
                    tree.deleteNode(command[1])
                elif commandL == 3:
                    tree.deleteNode(command[1], command[2])

        elif cmdPrompt == '-m':
            if commandL != 3 and commandL != 4:
                print("Incorrect amount of arguments")
                continue
            elif commandL == 3:
                tree.modifyNode(command[1], command[2])
            elif commandL == 4:
                tree.modifyNode(command[1], command[2], command[3])

        elif cmdPrompt == '-s':
            if commandL != 2:
                print("Incorrect amount of arguments")
                continue
            else:
                fName = command[1] + '.p'
                pickle.dump(tree, open(fName, 'wb'))
                print("Successfully saved to file '%s'" % fName)

        elif cmdPrompt == '-l':
            if commandL != 2:
                print("Incorrect amount of arguments")
                continue
            else:
                fName = command[1] + '.p'
                tree = pickle.load(open(fName, 'rb'))
                print("Successfully loaded tree '%s'" % fName)
    except BaseException as error:
        print("Something went wrong: %s" % error)


print('done')
```

Right now, I am traversing through the tree using the pre-order way I think -

1. print current node
2. check if there are any children nodes
3. if children do exist, run steps 1 and 2 on every child of the node

This tree is not binary, meaning that every node can have any number of children, not limited by left or right.

I already tried sending the level and needed symbol to each child, given how many children each node has, but it didn't work as the tree got more complicated.

Comment: Not too sure the problem you're having? Just put the unicode in the strings where tabs are, conditional checks to see if there are sub-children to determine which tree character to use. Unicode support is built in. Also I noticed you're not using any __repr__()'s at all. If you can clarify, after taking a look at those things I could further help. Your code isn't very pythonic, I can also help with that factoring, but I need clarification. It looks like you just came from C++. Also, use f-strings. In fact it might be worth posting this to code review in full.

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 Thanks for your reply, I have looked into __repr__ and __str__ and they look like they could be useful, but I don't see how I could implement them. I know that I should use f-strings but I am used to using placeholders, which I admit I have to change. When you said my code deosn't look that pythonic, can you give me an example so I can fix it. Also, I will send my code to code review when I have finished this concept. I haven't started learning C++ yet, I mostly code in python, although I don't have that much experience in it.

Comment: THere's a lot of minor things, it'd honestly be easier for me to rewrite it. It's not TOO bad, I'd hammer the concept out first. For `__repr__` if you just put print_Nodes into `__repr__` (more or less) then you can just do `print(treeObj)` instead of `treeObj.print_Nodes()` The print_Nodes function itself is probably the worst offender. I'll get back to you more in depth later, but I need to set some time aside. Get out of your comfort zone, learn about iterators, generators, lambdas, list comprehensions, dunder methods, just spend 20-30 minutes each day watching a youtube video or similar :)

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 Thanks for your feedback, I will look into waht you suggested. I don't really uses classes that much, which mostly explains my lack of knowledge of dunder methods.

Comment: Yeah see, when you start using all the built in features, your code will become more concise and easier to read. That's what it is to have pythonic code. Don't worry about it, everyone starts somewhere, and just moving forward is all that matters! There's so many things in Python that is no small task to learn it even though the entrance fee is low. You have a good mindset, but remember, a lack of knowledge is not a lack of opportunity to learn :) Do that, just read up on python intermediate stuff like i listed. I'll get back to you when I can, also to see what you've come up with.